# Node JS MySQL - Inserting Data.. No Rows updates in Database

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection

I am trying to Insert Data in Database through Node JS. Code working good showing "Record Inserted" msgs but no rows getting updated in MySQL.

This is the code where i am performing insert operation

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM menu WHERE item_name=\'' + userResponces[2].toLowerCase() + '\'', function(err, rows){
        if (err) throw err;
        else{
            i_id = rows[0].item_id;
            console.log('i_id ' + i_id);


    connection.query('INSERT INTO customer VALUES(default,' + c_name + ',' + c_addr + ',' + c_mob + ')', function(err, res){
        if(err.fatal){
            console.log(''+err.message);
        } 
        else{
            console.log("Record Inserted");


    connection.query('SELECT MAX(customer_id) AS c_id FROM customer', function(err, res){
        if(err) throw err;
        else{
            c_id = parseInt(res[0].c_id) + 1;
            console.log('c_id ' + c_id);


    console.log(i_id + ' ' + c_id + ' ' + qty);
    connection.query('INSERT INTO order1() VALUES(default,' + i_id + ',' + c_id + ',' + qty + ',1)', function(err, res){
        if(err) throw err;
        else
            console.log("Record Inserted");
    });
            }
    });
        }
    });    
            }
    });
```

In above code SELECT statement working perfectly, so undoubtedly no error in connection. Still this is for connection.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'nodeuser',
   password : 'password',
   database : 'foodorder'
 });

connection.connect(function(err){
if(!err) {
    console.log("Database is connected ...");    
} else {
    console.log("Error connecting database ...");    
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first condition tests err.fatal.
But if the query returns a SQL error like ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE, err object hasn't a fatal property.

```
{ [Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'bad_table_name' doesn't exist]
  code: 'ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE',
  errno: 1146,
  sqlState: '42S02',
  index: 0 }
```

So, here, you should test on `err` rather than `err.fatal`

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO customer VALUES(default,' + c_name + ',' + c_addr + ',' + c_mob + ')', function(err, res){
    if (err){
        return console.log(err);
    } 
    else{
        console.log("Record Inserted");
    // ...
});
```

Btw, think about [escaping values](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values) :

```
connection.query(
   'INSERT INTO customer VALUES(default, ?, ?, ?)',
   [c_name, c_addr, c_mob],
   function(err, res) {
       //...
   }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help :)